# How to plot multiple periods using pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, signals

everyone!

I'm learning about signals now, but I'm having a tough time trying to plot more than one period using pyplot. I don't know if the problem is with the mathematical part or with the code itself. I think this is a silly question, but any help would be great!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def function(t):
    return t**2


# Fundamental Period and Frequency:
T = 2*np.pi
w = 2*np.pi/T

# Defining the limits and the x values(in our case, time):
inferior_limit, superior_limit = -np.pi, np.pi
time_values = np.linspace(inferior_limit, superior_limit, 1000)

# Desired function plot:
plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.plot(time_values, function(time_values), color='k')
plt.show()
```

This is what is begin plot:
[image]

And this is what I would like to plot:
[image]

Comment: Unnecessary part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that `t²` is not a periodic function. The graph of the function you want is `(((t + π) % (2π)) - π)²` ([graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ax0aihl5dv)).

You can implement that in the `function` function as:

```
def function(t):
    return (((t + np.pi) % (2*np.pi)) - np.pi)**2
```

Just changing that should give the output:
[image: signal]